# Prove that if $A,B\in M_n(\mathbb{F})$ are $(n-1)$-nilpotent then they are similar.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, nilpotence

> If $A,B\in M_n(\mathbb{F})$ are $n-1$ nilpotent, prove they are similar.

Can I say that, since their minimal polynomial is $X^{n-1}$ they are similar?

I know that If $A,B$ are similar, they have the same minimal polynomial. Does it work the other way?

Comment: Do you have available the Jordan Canonical Form?

Comment: No, it's not true that two matrices with the same minimal polynomial are similar.  Take nilpotent matrices with Jordan blocks 2, 1, 1 and Jordan blocks 2, 2.

Comment: However, in this case you nkow that there is a Jordan block n-1.  The other Jordan block must be 1.  So there are no other possibilities.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your question about minimal polynomial and similar matrices, if you take the two following matrices:

$$\begin{pmatrix} 
\lambda & 1 &0 &0\\
0 & \lambda &0 &0\\
0 & 0 &\lambda &1\\
0 & 0 &0 &\lambda\\
\end{pmatrix}
$$
$$\begin{pmatrix} 
\lambda & 1 &0 &0\\
0 & \lambda &0 &0\\
0 & 0 &\lambda &0\\
0 & 0 &0 &\lambda\\
\end{pmatrix}
$$

These two matrices have the same minimal polynomial, $(X-\lambda)^2$, but they are not similar. Even if your matrix is nilpotent in which case $\lambda =0.$

Comment: These matrices aren't $n-1$-nilpontent though.

Comment: @GitGud indeed, it does work for the case of (n-1) nilpotent matrices as user148177 mentionned above